# Реализация чисел Фибоначчи с помощью хвостовой рекурсии в Haskell

Tags: функции, рекурсия, haskell, функциональное-программирование, числа-фибоначчи

Решаю задачу с рядом фибоначчи (+ отрицательные). Приблизительно так:

```
fibonacci 0 = 0
fibonacci 1 = 1
fibonacci n | n == 0 = 1
                 | n > 0 = fibonacci (n - 1) + fibonacci (n - 2)
                 | n < 0 = fibonacci (n + 2) - fibonacci (n + 1)
```

нужно увеличить скорость просчета. для этого естественно нужен аккумулятор.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Для начала решить рекуррентное уравнение, задающее эту последовательность, и найти формулу n-го члена.

Comment: Ничего не понял, поэтому плюсану. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правильнее всего, конечно, использовать готовую формулу `n`-ого члена :) Но для случая, когда нужно находить программным путём, подходит следующая идея (пишу алгоритм, не знаю синтаксис Хаскеля):

```
fib n = helper 0 1 n
  where helper curr prev n
          | n == 0   = curr
          | n > 0    = helper (curr+prev) curr (n-1)
          | n < 0    = helper prev (curr-prev) (n+1)
```

Это вычисляет последовательность за линейное время с хвостовой рекурсией.

Comment: `fibhelper` стоило бы сделать локальным идентификатором, а не глобальным. Как-то так: `fib n = helper 0 1 n where helper curr prev n = ...`

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Я не знаю синтаксис, честно, и мне даже негде попробовать. Если вы знаете, как исправить, подправьте прямо в ответе, хорошо? (Например, я не могу оценить качество [этой правки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/110006).)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Спасибо!